# Implicitly unwrapped optional values and using its value if nill

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Apple Documentation says the following about implicit unwrapped optional.

> **NOTE**
>
> If an implicitly unwrapped optional is nil and you try to access its
>   wrapped value, you’ll trigger a runtime error. The result is exactly
>   the same as if you place an exclamation mark after a normal optional
>   that does not contain a value.

So far, so good . But if we see that reference of any UI properties are implicitly unwrapped optional. I have been doing this -

```
@IBOutlet weak var lbleemsx: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nmtxtfld: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad()

    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      lbleemsx.text = nmtxtfld!.text


    }
```

Now If user doesn't type anything in the textfield, the value of `nmtxtfld!.text` is nil  and since I am using its value in my code then it should return error but It doesn't. Why so?

Comment: If nothing is entered the value of `text` will be `""`, which isn't technically `nil`. It's just an empty string.

Comment: @Arc676  So I have not used any type of code to do so or is it by default.

Comment: (Theoretically, I don't really do iOS) If you try to get the contents of an empty text view, you will get an empty string. That doesn't make it `nil`. I'm not sure if this changes in Swift.

Comment: sometimes in swift weak variables are release the memory on suddenly , so in this place use Strong or check the nil condition for assign the value

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik   
Okay fine but my question is according to documentation if you are using an implicitly unwrapped variable's value in your code and if it has nill or no value then it should result in an error, but why doesn't it happen when my text field's text is nill or my text field has no text. Why doesn't my application crash then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a little bit confused.  In this case it is `nmtxtfld` - the UITextField instance that is the implicitly unwrapped optional.  This property isn't nil because it is set when you instantiate your view controller from a NIB file or storyboard scene.  If you just allocated a new instance of your view controller without a NIB or storyboard then `nmtxtfld` would be nil and you would get a runtime exception when you tried to access it.

The reason that accessing `nmtxtfld.text` doesn't give a runtime exception is, that as other people have explained in comments and answers, when a UITextField is empty, it's `text` property isn't nil, it is an empty string `""`

The `text` property is an optional, so it *could* be nil, but in this case you are assigning it to the `text` property of a `UILabel`, whose `text` property is also an optional, so even if `nmtxtfld.text` *were* nil the assignment would be OK because you can assign nil to an optional.

If `nmtxtfld.text` was nil and you said something like `let aString=nmtxtfld.text!` then you would get a runtime exception because you have explicitly unwrapped a nil.

Comment: so usually text field is never nil, if also its empty.

Comment: It will only be nil if you assign nil to it. As per the documentation the default value of text is ""